# Remove Desktop entry from Alt+Tab list

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-registry, alt-tab

Is it possible to remove the entry for the desktop from Windows 7's Alt+Tab list? So far I have found a [post](http://www.annoyances.org/exec/forum/winvista/1229369134) telling me to add an entry to the registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Explorer/AltTabSettings
```

However, this reverts the Alt+Tab menu back to the Windows XP style where you don't get window previews. I just want to remove the desktop entry from the list.

Comment: Before we get too far, mind giving us an explanation why you want to remove it? Perhaps there is a better way to accomplish the real task at hand.

Comment: I'm not the OP, but I want it gone because its a feature that has never been useful, but often gets in the way. I say never been useful because if I wanted that functionality I'd reach for win+d, not hit alt tab until I select desktop. It gets in the way in that especially with how Google Hangouts Chrome Extension works, somehow 'desktop' ends up being the next app so I frequently end up cycling to it on accident.

Comment: I'd like to remove it because it is totally unnecessary.  Windows D switches to the desktop, or restores the view if at the desktop.  It is simply clutter.  There are some interesting solutions below but some simply remove the Desktop icon and leave everything else the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not a fix, a replacement.

This might do it: http://insentient.net/

or: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/windows-7vistaxp-alt-tab-replacement/

Answer (score 8):

[Option A](https://superuser.com/a/126949/169199) - without any software or registry hack

1. Hold down the left alt key Press and release the right alt key
2. keeping the left alt key held down Then, still keeping the left alt
3. key held down, tab-tab-tab away

Option B - with a tool from lifehacker

[System tweaking utility Alt+Tab Tuner](http://lifehacker.com/5507473/alt%252Btab-tuner-makes-windows-7s-task-switcher-thumbnails-larger-and-much-more)

[Option C](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Is_there_any_way_how_to_remove_desktop_item_from_Win_Tab_or_Alt_Tab_switcher_of_Windows_Vista) - Registry Hack

Create a DWORD Value called **AltTabSettings** in HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Explorer and set it to **1**.

Gives the "old" XP styled Alt-Tab without desktop.

--

Found also a tip, love it: **Windows Key + Tab** for an over-the-top graphic preview.

Comment: That was very informative. The first tip is really useful!

Comment: The registry hack removes the desktop option but completely changes the look to not show the content of the windows - just the icon of the app.

Comment: The download links from the Lifehacker article are now both dead.  I found Alt+Tab Tuner at http://download.cnet.com/Alt-Tab-Tuner/3000-18487_4-75181434.html and at http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.5 and at http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.205 with Windows 8 support which vaguely looks like the original author's site.

Comment: To my disappointment, Alt+Tab Tuner does not seem to offer anything better than the registry hack as far as skipping the Desktop icon is concerned.

Comment: Option A doesn't seem to work with Windows 8.1. Though the Desktop does actually disappear from the **alt-tab** list, I now see extra hidden windows appear, such as the search pane.

Comment: Windows 8.1: Registry hack works, but constantly shows 3-4 ghost windows without a title.

Answer (score 4):

Is the reason you don't want Desktop in Alt+Tab, because of it interfering with cycling through windows you've minimized, and back?

IF SO: add these three commands to AutoHotKey, which allow you to still have Desktop entry in alt+tab, but with keyboard shortcuts, allows you to restore, in order, the windows that you minimize (in order):

```
#s::Send,{AltDown}{Esc}{AltUp}{LWinDown}

#a::
Send,{AltDown}{ShiftDown}{Esc}{ShiftUp}{AltUp}{LWinDown}
Sleep, 0
WinMaximize,A
return

#x::
WinMaximize,A
WinMinimize,A
return
```

Substitute the `Win+S`, `Win+A` and `Win+X` input keys for whatever you like. Full info, see my thread on the "solution" [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic71095.html).

Answer (score 0):

[DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/) has an alt+tab replacement that works pretty much just like the windows 7 one, except has an option not to show the Desktop window.