# On Windows, is there any way to remove the desktop icon from the alt-tab menu?

Tags: windows-7, alt-tab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove Desktop entry from Alt+Tab list](https://superuser.com/questions/80157/remove-desktop-entry-from-alttab-list)

I've recently begun using Windows 7, and I don't like having the Desktop showing up as another application in the alt-tab menu.  (If I need to switch to the Desktop I'll use Windows-D or the right-hand side of the taskbar.  Treating it as an application destroys the metaphor of the Desktop being *behind* your applications.)

Is there any way to get rid of this from the alt-tab menu?  (*Without* resorting to a registry hack to switch to the XP alt-tab menu.)

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any way to do it besides reverting to the XP alt+tab. Everywhere I'm reading says it's not possible. I thought there might be third party alt+tab functionality applications that wouldn't have it, but I can't even find any of those.