# Removing desktop from Alt + Tab on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7

I have a 64-bit Windows 7 PC. When I press Alt + Tab or WinKey + Tab , it shows the current windows including the desktop, but I don't want to show the desktop there. I tried solutions given for Windows 7 32-bit, but they didn't work. Is there any registry hack to solve this problem?

Comment: This has been asked *so* many times before that I'm sure you should have seen it under related questions while posting. Duplicate of [Remove Desktop entry from Alt+Tab list](http://superuser.com/questions/80157/remove-desktop-entry-from-alttab-list), [On Windows, is there any way to remove the desktop icon from the alt-tab menu?](http://superuser.com/questions/368701/on-windows-is-there-any-way-to-remove-the-desktop-icon-from-the-alt-tab-menu), [Can you remove the desktop entry from alt+tab in windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/445064/can-you-remove-the-desktop-entry-from-alttab) ...

Comment: // , This question comes up on Google, though.

Answer (score 8):

Try:

### 1

Open Registry Editor by typing **regedit** in Start Menu search box or press <kbd>[image]</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type **regedit**.

In the Registry Editor, navigate to:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Software > Microsoft > Windows > CurrentVersion >
> Explorer

In the Explorer folder ("subkey"), create a new DWORD value, named **AltTabSettings**.

(Right-click > New > DWORD (32-bit) Value).

Double-click the newly created DWORD value, change it's value to *1* instead of *0*, and choose *Hexadecimal*.

Press OK, and enjoy the classic Alt-Tab feature.

### 2

Another option would be to use the software [Switcher](http://insentient.net/Index.html).

- Requires Aero enabled.
- More informations read [this](http://insentient.net/Switcher/Overview.html)

Comment: On Windows 8.1 this workaround does remove the Desktop from the **alt-tab** list, but also has the nasty side-effect of showing a number of hidden windows, such as "PC settings" and "Store".